# Grafana Mimir Query 404 Not Found in Grafana

Tags: grafana-mimir

I'm working on Mimir configuration as a single node.

And I have 404 error trying to add a data source in Grafana. I suppose there is an error in Mimir configuration. Could someone prompt me?

Grafana site has much documentation, but it is mainly for Kubernetes and lacks descriptions of how to run Mimir on a single node.

```yaml
multitenancy_enabled: false
no_auth_tenant: "rnd"

frontend_worker:
  frontend_address: '0.0.0.0:9095'
  scheduler_address: ""
  dns_lookup_duration: 10s

common:
  storage:
    backend: s3
    s3:
      endpoint: s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
      region: eu-central-1
      secret_access_key: {{ aws_s3_secret_key }} # This is a secret injected via an environment variable
      access_key_id: {{ aws_s3_id_key }} # This is a secret injected via an environment variable

blocks_storage:
  storage_prefix: blocks
  s3:
    bucket_name: {{ bucket_name_data }}

  tsdb:
    dir: /tmp/mimir/tsdb
    ship_interval: 1m
    block_ranges_period: [ 2h ]
    retention_period: 2h

  bucket_store:
    sync_dir: /tmp/mimir/tsdb-sync

alertmanager_storage:
  storage_prefix: alerts
  s3:
    bucket_name: {{ bucket_name_alertmanager}}

ruler_storage:
  storage_prefix: ruler
  s3:
    bucket_name: {{ bucket_name_rules }}

compactor:
  data_dir: /tmp/mimir/compactor

store_gateway:
  sharding_ring:
    replication_factor: 1

server:
  http_listen_address: 0.0.0.0
  http_listen_port: 9009

limits:
  compactor_blocks_retention_period: 1y

distributor:
  ring:
    instance_addr: 0.0.0.0
    kvstore:
      store: memberlist
  pool:
    health_check_ingesters: true

ingester:
  ring:
    instance_addr: 0.0.0.0
    min_ready_duration: 0s
    final_sleep: 0s
    num_tokens: 512

    kvstore:
      store: memberlist
    replication_factor: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found in configuration file

```yaml
api:
    skip_label_name_validation_header_enabled: false
    alertmanager_http_prefix: /alertmanager
    prometheus_http_prefix: /prometheus
```

So correct URL is like this `http://0.0.0.0:9090/prometheus`